# gulp.watch triggered twice on renaming file

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch

Everytime I rename a file in **`srcDir`**, build-task get triggered twice, and they run concurrently too.

While the first build-task-instance run, the second instance clean-task triggered, causing weird errors and crash the gulp process entirely.

How can I stop this from happening ?

Here's the code:

```
// Clean task
gulp.task('clean', function () {
    return gulp.src(dstDir)
        .pipe(plugins.clean({ read: false }));
});

// Build task
gulp.task('build', ['clean'], function() {
    gulp.src(srcDir)
        .pipe(plugins.imagemin()) // Just for example, not neccessary exactly the same
        .gulp.dest(dstDir);
});

// Watch task
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch(srcDir, ['build']);
});
```

The plugin I used for cleaning is [gulp-clean](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-clean)

Comment: Typo? `gulp.tash` (in the watch task section)

Comment: @J.Titus Ya, that was a typo. Thank you for pointing that out

Comment: I can make all tasks run sequentially, but that's kinda ugly and I really don't want to do that

Comment: Similar issue :) https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/1074

Comment: *facepalm* `gulp-watch` is different from `gulp.watch`.. never mind. :)

Comment: Yea gulp-watch uses chokidar instead of gaze (native gulp#watch). Heard that they finally used chokidar in 4.0 and got rid of lots of issues